# How to change private zone route53 value using scripts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I am new to AWS and Route 53 concepts. I need to change the private zone route53 **value** using scripts, but could not find anything related to this. How can i do this ?

Example:
Domain Name : secuirty-dev.com
Zone ID: Z28764Y5YERE
Value:10.0.0.1

Change To:
Domain Name : secuirty-dev.com
Zone ID: Z28764Y5YERE
Value:10.0.0.9

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here ([v1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html), [v2](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/route53/change-resource-record-sets.html)) is the command documentation for updating the records in Route53 hosted zones. Use the `UPSERT` operation to update the existing record. Make sure that the AWS CLI has been installed and the proper privilages are there.

Comment: Thank you @Praveen Sripati. I am able to get the current record set value into a file using below script. But, how to create a JSON file with the new value to to use the UPSERT oper.                   
#!/bin/bash
#Variable Declaration - Change These
HOSTED_ZONE_ID="Z2ABYTEDY"
NAME="asdf.com."
TYPE="CNAME"
TTL=300

#get current record set IP from Route 53
aws route53 list-resource-record-sets --hosted-zone-id $HOSTED_ZONE_ID | \
jq -r '.ResourceRecordSets[] | select (.Name == "'"$NAME"'") | select (.Type == "'"$TYPE"'") | .ResourceRecords[0].Value' > /tmp/current_route53_value